# What is the theological difference between conviction and condemnation?

Tags: sanctification

Can one compare the results between conviction and condemnation in a persons life?

Comment: According to which faith's doctrine?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You ask about the "theological" difference between two terms but you did not specify which theology.  According to Orthodox dogmatic theology, Roman Catholic theology, or some Protestant systematic theology or something else?   It seems your question was closed in any case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did not know there were so many different origins of theology. I will keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conviction** is knowing that you did wrong.

**Condemnation** is bearing the guilt of wrongdoing and suffering the punishment for it.

A Christian may be convicted of their wrongdoing, i.e. they recognize it has happened and that it was their fault. They may and probably should feel bad about it, However they know that they will not have to suffer eternal punishment for it (condemnation).

Christian therapists often make the distinction that conviction says "You did bad" while condemnation says "You are bad."

Answer (score 0):

RO 8:1 1

> There is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ
>   Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit.

If you are born again there is no condemnation.  You have hope, grace and mercy that God will forgive you, if you will repent.   God dose not condem the repented.  Condemnation says there is no hope.
Satan tries to condem and say there is no hope, no use, give up.
God convicts: hey you are wrong, repent and I will forgive.

Comment: Cross-reference for Romans 8:1 is also John 3:17 (the verse after the most famous verse)